# JPA ManyToOne Cascade On UPDATE with JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this **Parent class**

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@NamedQuery(name = "category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c")

public class Category implements Serializable {

    public Category(){}

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "col2")
    private Boolean col2;

}
```

And i have referenced the parent table in **child table** as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "cat_name")
    private Category category
```

when i run this JPQL query

```
update  Category c SET c.name=:newName ,c.termsCanHaveChildren=:canHaveChdrn where c.name=:oldName
```

it's return with foreign key constraint error while i have put **Cascade All** in child field

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`terms`.`term`, CONSTRAINT `FKaykenypxci167nqioh4xx9p3a` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_name`) REFERENCES `category` (`name`))
```

Comment: Cascading flags do not apply to BULK UPDATE JPQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays at the constraint being generated by your persistence provider (`hibernate`), for the `@JoinColumn(name = "cat_name")` at the child table (and not with the `CascadeType` that you're defining)...

The generated constraint should indicated that when the PK of Category is Updated, any reference to such column should be updated also...

I believe this configuration should work (but you need to test it first, because I always generated my database model using scripts and not using hibernate features):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(
    name = "cat_name", 
    foreignKey = @ForeingKey(
        name = "fk_child_category",
        foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (cat_name) REFERENCES category ON UPDATE CASCADE"
    )
)
private Category category;
```

Also you need to check if your database supports "ON UPDATE CASCADE"... According to this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034), oracle does not... (What database are you using?)

If this does not work, try the suggestion of Michelle...

Answer (score 0):

That's expected: you are changing the Primary Key (@Id), that's used in a Foreign Key (@JoinColumn).

Use a surrogated **immutable** primary key.